# Libraries for creating surfaces output in geotiff

Tags: gdal

I am looking for some libraries that can assist me in creating geotiffs from 3d polygons that becomes surfaces.

Given a set of polygons where each node is [x,y,z] coordinates, i would like to create a geotiff at a given resolution [r] that has elevation of the polygon at each sample point, such i can use it to subtract from DSM.

It is to be used to generate a surface that a DSM cannot penetrate. which can be found by subtracting the DSM from the geotiff surface generated from the 3d polygons above.

Do anyone have examples of libraries, it do not matter what the framework is - can be python or anything else.

It could also be combined to solve the real problem above such the intermediate step of creating a geotiff is not needed and it outputs the difference of the polygons to the DSM right away. Anyway, i need a way to represent 3d polygons and use them to subtract from DSMs.

(I dont want to be dependant on QGIS or other desktop installed software).

Can GDAL or PDAL solve the problem?

Comment: Can you provide a small subset of the polygons you are working with?

Comment: That is also one of my tasks to figure out what format to represent the polygons in. Exporting to geojson from global mapper dont include the elevation. Any suggestions for formats that would be good to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to *rasterize* a 3D-polygon to a 2D raster while containing the Z value as for each raster cell/pixel.

This should be possible with the `-3d` option of [`gdal_rasterize`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html).

**-3d**:

*Indicates that a burn value should be extracted from the "Z" values of the feature. These values are added to the burn value given by "-burn value" or "-a attribute_name" if provided. As of now, only points and lines are drawn in 3D.*

Comment: Thanks, seems like its the right fit.  I will do some tests with it atleast

Comment: We tried to export a shape file with areas that include z elevation values for each vertex, but the gdal_rasterize produced a geotiff that had same elevation in all polygons (maybe an average and not a slope as expected)

Comment: Can you provide a subset of the shapefile? One feature/polygon should be enough for testing.

Comment: sure, http://chilp.it/40ff6e3 - you can also reach me at pks@s-innovatons.net / @pksorensen on twitter

Comment: It turs out that it could be an issue with shape files.

Comment: I actually never got this to work, if you @kersten have a blog post/example of it working with rasterize no a area where vertexes defines the heights and it should interpolate between these i am open ears.